# Centering a text while using wrapfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, geometry, wrapfigure

I would like to ask why it is not possible to center a text/equation just after using a wrapfigure that allows to create a customized box.

For instance, I would like to avoid to obtain this configuration :

[image]

The code is the following (I have took the structure of the box from another post of this forum):

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%%%%%%MATHS%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{accents} % for bar under character

\DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}



\usepackage {mcode}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white


\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\definecolor{BgYellow}{HTML}{FFF59C}
\definecolor{FrameYellow}{HTML}{F7A600}


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}
\geometry{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
\newcommand{\gap}{\vspace{0.25cm}} 
\newcommand{\gapi}{\vspace{1.25cm}} 
 \usepackage{parskip}
 \usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, matrix, positioning}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newtcolorbox{mybox1}[1][]{enhanced,
before skip=0mm,after skip=0mm,
width=0.35\textwidth,
colback=BgYellow,colframe=FrameYellow,boxrule=0.2mm,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0cm,yshift*=0mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
boxed title style={frame code={
\path[left color=FrameYellow,right color=FrameYellow,
middle color=FrameYellow]
([xshift=-0mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=0mm]frame.north east)
[rounded corners=0mm]-- ([xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm]frame.north east)
-- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
-- ([xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm]frame.north west)
[sharp corners]-- cycle;
},interior engine=empty,
},
  sharp corners,rounded corners=southeast,arc is angular,arc=3mm,
  underlay={%
    \path[fill=BgYellow!80!black] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    \path[draw=FrameYellow,shorten <=-0.05mm,shorten >=-0.05mm,color=FrameYellow] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    },
  drop fuzzy shadow,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title={#1}}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%MEMO%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.35\textwidth}
\begin{mybox1}[Mémo]
Soit $z = x+iy$ :
\begin{dmath*}
arg(z) = \left\{ \begin{aligned}
\pi + \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) \condition{si $x <0$} \\
\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) \condition{si $x >0$}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{dmath*}
\end{mybox1}
\end{wrapfigure}

Il reste ensuite à déterminer les constantes restantes $C$ et $D$ en usant des conditions sur le bord du domaine $x=L$ telles que :
\gap
 \begin{equation}
  \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
        F''(x=L) &= 2 \alpha^2 e^{-\alpha L} \left[C \sin \left({\alpha L} \right) - D \cos \left({\alpha L} \right) \right] = 0     \\
        \\
        F(x=L)  &=   e^{-\alpha L} \left[C \cos \left({\alpha L} \right) + D \sin \left({\alpha L} \right) \right] = (h_{N} - h_{\infty})  \\
     \end{aligned}
    \right.
    \notag
\end{equation}

En résolvant ce système, on détermine les valeurs des constantes associées :

 \begin{equation}
  \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
        C&= e^{\alpha L} (h_{N} - h_{\infty}) \cos\left(\frac{L}{B^{\frac{1}{4}}\sqrt{2}}\right)   \\
        D  &=  e^{\alpha L} (h_{N} - h_{\infty}) \sin\left(\frac{L}{B^{\frac{1}{4}}\sqrt{2}}\right)   \\
     \end{aligned}
    \right.
    \notag
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Maybe you should use `minipage`s if you want to control  vertical alignment

Comment: @NBur I have tried mini pages : it works to center the text but then the text situated just after is completely disorganized... Maybe I am doing it wrong ? I would be glad if you could show me how do you want to write it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an optional parameter to `wrapfigure` to indicate the number of narrow lines. With `\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{L}{0.35\textwidth}` you get

[image: b]

Comment: Dips Thank you for the help. I didn't know about this parameter: it helps a lot.